# STM32 I2C Issues with NFC Chip

Tags: c++, nfc, stm32, i2c, stm32cubeide

I've created a PCB with a [STM32F207ZET6](https://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/STMicroelectronics/STM32F207ZET6?qs=L6eUzyzWLAvlPJjr0ZD%2FHw%3D%3D) and it has an [NXP NFC](https://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/771-NT3H2211W0FTTJ) chip connected via I2C.
The problem that I am having is that I can not communicate with the NFC chip.

I have verified the I2C connection between the ARM chip and NFC.
I have verified that both chips are getting the correct power.
I am using stm32cube IDE with a stlink-v3.
I configured the I2C1 pins and wrote the following code.

**What I have tried**

- I have tried to use `HAL_I2C_IsDeviceReady()` to see if the NFC was connected. This returns true, but it also returns true on every address that I put in there.
- I have tried to send commands and also read them back into a buffer array. All that was returned was 0.

```
    cmds[1] = 0x60;
    cmds[2] = 0x00;
    HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit(&hi2c1, nfc_Adr_w, cmds, 2, HAL_MAX_DELAY);

    HAL_Delay(15);

    HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit(&hi2c1, nfc_Adr_w, cmds, 1, HAL_MAX_DELAY);

    HAL_I2C_Master_Receive(&hi2c1, nfc_Adr_r, buffer, 1, HAL_MAX_DELAY);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

**Full Code**

```
#include "main.h"

/* Private variables ---------------------------------------------------------*/
I2C_HandleTypeDef hi2c1;

/* Private function prototypes -----------------------------------------------*/
void SystemClock_Config(void);
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void);
static void MX_I2C1_Init(void);

unsigned char buffer[150];
unsigned char cmds[3];
_Bool results = 0;
uint8_t devices = 0u;
int deviceReady = 0u;
/* Private user code ---------------------------------------------------------*/

/**
  * @brief  The application entry point.
  * @retval int
  */
int main(void)
{
    uint8_t nfc_Adr_w = 0b10101010;
    uint8_t nfc_Adr_r = 0b10101011;
  /* MCU Configuration--------------------------------------------------------*/

  /* Reset of all peripherals, Initializes the Flash interface and the Systick. */
  HAL_Init();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN Init */

  /* USER CODE END Init */

  /* Configure the system clock */
  SystemClock_Config();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SysInit */

  /* USER CODE END SysInit */

  /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_I2C1_Init();
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */

  /* USER CODE END 2 */

  /* Infinite loop */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */

  while (1)
  {
    /* USER CODE END WHILE */

      //HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit();

      //HAL_I2C_Master_Receive();
      cmds[0] = 0x00;
      cmds[1] = 0x60;
      cmds[2] = 0x00;
      HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit(&hi2c1, nfc_Adr_w, cmds, 2, HAL_MAX_DELAY);

      HAL_Delay(15);

      HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit(&hi2c1, nfc_Adr_w, cmds, 1, HAL_MAX_DELAY);

      HAL_I2C_Master_Receive(&hi2c1, nfc_Adr_r, buffer, 1, HAL_MAX_DELAY);

//    deviceReady = HAL_I2C_IsDeviceReady(&hi2c1, 0x3C, 3u, 10u);
//    printf("Searching for I2C devices on the bus...\n");
        /* Values outside 0x03 and 0x77 are invalid. */
//      for (uint8_t i = 0x03u; i < 0x78u; i++)
//      {
//        uint8_t address = i << 1u;
//        /* In case there is a positive feedback, print it out. */
//        if (HAL_OK == HAL_I2C_IsDeviceReady(&hi2c1, address, 3u, 10u))
//        {
////            printf("Device found: 0x%02X\n", address);
//          devices++;
//          results = 1;
//        }
//        if (HAL_TIMEOUT == HAL_I2C_IsDeviceReady(&hi2c1, address, 3u, 10u)) {
//            devices++;
//        }
//        deviceReady = HAL_I2C_IsDeviceReady(&hi2c1, address, 3u, 10u);
//      }
//      /* Feedback of the total number of devices. */
////        if (0u == devices)
////        {
//////        printf("No device found.\n");
////        }
////        else
////        {
////          printf("Total found devices: %d\n", devices);
////        }
      HAL_Delay(1000u);
      devices = 0u;
    /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
  }
  /* USER CODE END 3 */
}

/**
  * @brief System Clock Configuration
  * @retval None
  */
void SystemClock_Config(void)
{
  RCC_OscInitTypeDef RCC_OscInitStruct = {0};
  RCC_ClkInitTypeDef RCC_ClkInitStruct = {0};

  /** Initializes the CPU, AHB and APB busses clocks 
  */
  RCC_OscInitStruct.OscillatorType = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSI;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSIState = RCC_HSI_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSICalibrationValue = RCC_HSICALIBRATION_DEFAULT;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLState = RCC_PLL_NONE;
  if (HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&RCC_OscInitStruct) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /** Initializes the CPU, AHB and APB busses clocks 
  */
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.ClockType = RCC_CLOCKTYPE_HCLK|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_SYSCLK
                              |RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK1|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK2;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKSource = RCC_SYSCLKSOURCE_HSI;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLKDivider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB1CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB2CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;

  if (HAL_RCC_ClockConfig(&RCC_ClkInitStruct, FLASH_LATENCY_0) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
}

/**
  * @brief I2C1 Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_I2C1_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN I2C1_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END I2C1_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN I2C1_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END I2C1_Init 1 */
  hi2c1.Instance = I2C1;
  hi2c1.Init.ClockSpeed = 100000;
  hi2c1.Init.DutyCycle = I2C_DUTYCYCLE_2;
  hi2c1.Init.OwnAddress1 = 0;
  hi2c1.Init.AddressingMode = I2C_ADDRESSINGMODE_7BIT;
  hi2c1.Init.DualAddressMode = I2C_DUALADDRESS_DISABLE;
  hi2c1.Init.OwnAddress2 = 0;
  hi2c1.Init.GeneralCallMode = I2C_GENERALCALL_DISABLE;
  hi2c1.Init.NoStretchMode = I2C_NOSTRETCH_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_I2C_Init(&hi2c1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN I2C1_Init 2 */

  /* USER CODE END I2C1_Init 2 */

}

/**
  * @brief GPIO Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void)
{
  GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct = {0};

  /* GPIO Ports Clock Enable */
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOC_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOB_CLK_ENABLE();

  /*Configure GPIO pin Output Level */
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(LED_GPIO_Port, LED_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);

  /*Configure GPIO pin : LED_Pin */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = LED_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(LED_GPIO_Port, &GPIO_InitStruct);

}

/* USER CODE BEGIN 4 */

/* USER CODE END 4 */

/**
  * @brief  This function is executed in case of error occurrence.
  * @retval None
  */
void Error_Handler(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN Error_Handler_Debug */
  /* User can add his own implementation to report the HAL error return state */

  /* USER CODE END Error_Handler_Debug */
}

#ifdef  USE_FULL_ASSERT
/**
  * @brief  Reports the name of the source file and the source line number
  *         where the assert_param error has occurred.
  * @param  file: pointer to the source file name
  * @param  line: assert_param error line source number
  * @retval None
  */
void assert_failed(uint8_t *file, uint32_t line)
{ 
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 6 */
  /* User can add his own implementation to report the file name and line number,
     tex: printf("Wrong parameters value: file %s on line %d\r\n", file, line) */
  /* USER CODE END 6 */
}
#endif /* USE_FULL_ASSERT */

/************************ (C) COPYRIGHT STMicroelectronics *****END OF FILE****/
```

Comment: Two things that pop in my mind. Did you check if you have the right resistors on the two I2C wires. Second, do you have an oscilloscope and can you check, if the signal is right? Or if any signal is given on the wires.

Comment: Is there a reason to use the NXP NFC chip ? I mean that ST provides its NFC chip that is probably much easier to integrate with a STM32.

Comment: The header of `HAL_I2C_IsDeviceReady()` mentions that "this function is used with memory devices". Are you sure it is appropriate for NFC ?

Comment: @skratchi.at The datasheet does not say anything about having resistors on the I2C wires, but is there some kind of standard that I am missing? If there is resistors required could I just use the pull-up resistors on the STM chip? I can check the signals when I get back to school.

Comment: @GuillaumePetitjean There is no reason to use an NPX NFC chip, I am not too familiar with ST ones. Anyones that you could recommend?

Comment: @kaydrae I2C requires pull-up resistors to work. All I2C outputs are open-collector-outputs. You can try to enable the pull-ups on your STM.

Comment: @skratchi.at Enabling the pull-ups on the STM did work. I am about to communicate with the chip now. Thank you.